# Russian words with negative connotation substituted by english ones

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова, история-языка

I'm looking for russian words that throughout the course of history acquired a negative connotation, because they were linked, for exemple,to the politics of Soviet Unione, and during the last years they were replaced by english positively connoted or neutralterms. An exemple are the words предприниматель, капиталист and промышленник that had a socio-political negative connotation linked to the soviet ideology and for this reason to talk about a businessman they introduced the term businessman from english. i hope you can give me good answers and they will help me to write my thesis

Comment: I think бизнесмен sounds more negative than предприниматель. Предприниматель sounds like "good бизнесмен".

Answer (score 2):

`приказчик` (mostly a pre-1917 reality) can be (to a degree) related with post-1991 `менеджер` (but, not to miss it from notice:
 a. `приказчик` is obsolete,
 b. there are other words of nowadays Russia to name old „приказчик“ in modern circumstances, and those words are NOT (based on) new loan-words, e. g.: *управляющий*, *продавец-консультант*, *ассистент*)
And, yes, the image of `приказчик` was, as a rule, definitely negative in Soviet books and movies I could see in the late USSR.

Answer (score 1):

`Офис` replacing `контора`, and I would maintain that this is *the* only example of what you're describing; anything else would be crossing into really heavy jargon (such as `эйчар` for `кадровик`) and/or trying to squeeze things in to fit a highly specific research topic — as with your 'businessman' example which, I'm afraid, does a rather poor job of describing both linguistic reality (`предприниматель` is actually more common than `бизнесмен`) and the processes that formed it (with `промышленник` and `капиталист`, it wasn't the connotations but the obsolescence; both sounded extremely Industrial Age).

Comment: Actually, эйчар and кадровик have different meanings. кадровик is a person who processes different stuff-related documents, and эйчар is a person who finds new people, shows them office, defining how to improve in-office atmosphere, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Барыга` (pusher, profiteer, illicit **dealer**) — now `дилер`

`нажива, барыш` [usage example](http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%22&clid=1836587&lr=144) (**margin**, spread) — now `маржа`

`торговец` (**trader**) — now `трейдер`

`бульварная пресса` (**tabloid**) — now `таблоид`

`хахаль` (**boyfriend**, suitor) — now `бойфренд`

`дешевый перевозчик` (**low cost**) — now `лоукостер`

for the sake of any other advantage I suggest searching the web for terms

`заимствованные слова`

`иностранные слова`

`модные иностранные словечки`

Comment: Most of the words on the left-hand side haven't really gone anywhere, and their contextual usages don't quite overlap with the new English borrowings.

Comment: @NikolayErshov    I agree that there was no its complete substitution.

Answer (score -3):

Слово "мерчендайзейзер" какое-то время вызывало некое, словно, почтение, своей претендующей величиной. Но спустя время, он превратился в простого "мерчика" с которым мы стали уже "на короткой".

Comment: И какое же слово на русском было таким "плохим" что ему пришлось срочно английский эквивалент искать? Товаровед?